# The trace-determinant plane, classification of equilibria of differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, determinant, trace

What are some easy ways to remember each of the different behaviors of general solutions of ordinary differential equations in the trace-determinant plane? For differential equations of the form $\frac{dY}{dt} = AY$ where $A$ is a $2 \times 2$-matrix and $Y$ is the column vector $(x\ y)$.

Comment: Just think first about whether the roots are real or complex (to do this, think about the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial, using the trace and determinant), and then think about the signs of the real parts.

Answer (score 1):

Stable solutions only occur when the trace $\tau \leq 0$ and the determinant $\Delta>0$.

So saddles occur when $\Delta<0$, and the non-isolated fixed points whenever $\Delta=0$ (the borderline).

When $\Delta>0$ the centers (these should seem interesting) occur at $\tau=0$.

After that, for $\Delta>0$, just try to recognize the symmetry of stability reversal on either side of the $\tau=0$ line. For example as you go away from the centers, you get spirals, then the borderline stars and degenerate nodes on the $\tau^2-4\Delta=0$ curve, and then the nodes.

I think I accidentally memorized this plane by solving examples of every type of equation that could possibly happen. Very useful for stability analysis by eye!

Comment: If you have access to *Mathematica*, I made a really cool manipulator that is fun to play with. You can see all (including eigenvalues) as you drag the 4 matrix values. I would only add it to this post if you wanted and could actually use it. Sometimes playing helps too eh.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few concepts to consider:

First of all you need to rebember that these such systems can be solved by writing down the eigenvalues (and theirs eingenvectors) to the plane, the eingenvectors show the diretion of expansion (or retraction) of the system, while the signal of the eingenvalues decide if it is a retraction or a expansion.

I usually reccor to these materials every time I need to remember these concepts in a quick way:

[Youtube ODE ovewview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvsnM3vgIHs)

[Trace-determinant plane](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~ddrake/pdf/linear-sys-stability.pdf)

PS.: Without time to go deeper in this issue, I should came back to review in a feew <s>weeks</s> years.

Answer (score 0):

I find the below caption for the trace-determinant plane a good reminder (this is taken from Hirsch, Smale and Devaney's *Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos* (3e, p.64)):

[image]